# how to get json values ​in url with php

Tags: php, php-7

I am trying to send json values ​​with a url by POST but I am not getting any value.

local test: http://127.0.0.1/test.php

with postman I send inside the body:

```
key: Token Value: xxyyz
```

my service code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$arrayData = json_decode($data);

var_dump($arrayData);
```

Return NULL, How can I return the values?

Comment: What does `var_dump($data)` show? How are you posting to this page? Form? Ajax? cURL?

Comment: Try to post data to a mock API endpoint such as https://beeceptor.com (there are many others), and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you send by Postman send body and then click on the option raw. Then you will see in the end of the line more options. (text, Javascript, JSON). Select JSON and insert your JSON String and send it to your server.

... and i hope that will work.  I tested with your php code and it works.

Comment: It works for me in raw format, but why doesn't it work for me in format-data?

Comment: @Leoh Because php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data". You should not attach the JSON as a file to your request, but add it as a request body to the post request, setting the Content-Type header (application/json). Then it will be available in php://input.

Then you have a problem. Once you use enctype="multipart/form-data", php://input will remain empty.

Comment: @Leoh But you can use $_POST instead of file_get_content. With the key you use for form-data, you can fetch your JSON on the serverside.